# wsdl bad url generation behind nginx haproxy

Tags: wsdl, nginx, ejb-3.0, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I am currently developing a webservice using jax-ws based on an EJB behind a nginx ssl offloader and a haproxy for the load balancing like :

```
@WebService()
@RolesAllowed("allowedOne")
@Stateless()
public class Account
{
    @WebMethod(operationName = "register")
    public RegisterOutTo register(
        @WebParam(name = "registerInTo") RegisterInTo RegisterInTo)
    {
        // do some stuffs
    }
}
```

https => http => WSDL generation => http => https

jax-ws doesn't seems to take care of x-forwarded-proto to generate the WSDL :

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://services/" schemaLocation="http://myprodserver.com:80/Services/Account?xsd=1" />
```

and

```
<soap:address location="http://myprodserver.com:80/Services/Account"/>
```

Of course, the clients can't find the xsd and the requests fails.

Is there something I miss.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally get through the problem patching the HttpAdapter class from the package 
`com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http` and repacking it onto the `glassfish/modules/webservices-osgi.jar`

We now detect if the x-forwarded-proto is set to https then replacing `http` by `https` into the final address and removing the port if necessary.

Comment: Could you shed more light on how you did this? Which methods in HttpAdapter did you edit?

Answer (score 0):

Also had to do this. Unfortunately you need to replace a glassfish (Version 5) module file:

```
glassfish/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
```

To do this clone https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws and modify the file

```
jaxws-ri/servlet/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/ServletConnectionImpl.java
```

Apply this patch: https://pastebin.com/HUcWNTJ6

The Header "X-Forwarded-Proto" will be parsed and used as the URL scheme. Final step is to replace the compiled .class file of ServletConnectionImpl in the webservices-osgi.jar.